# Use non-calculator to find the value of the modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

This is the question :

The complex number w has modulus r . Given that w satisfied

500/w = 3|w|  + 40i

. Use a non-calculator method to find the value of r.
I tried to solve it by calculator and I found that r is approximately equal to 16.2 . I do not know it is correct or not . I hope that I would be given a non-calculator method to solve this question . Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the modulus of both sides, square, now you have a quadratic equation in $q=|w|^2$ that you can solve.

Comment: I would have multiplied by $w$ before taking the modulus, but that's just me.

Comment: @Oscar: you would then have to deal with real and imaginary parts of $w$.

Comment: Use $|w(a+bw)|=|w|×|a+bw|$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the exponential notation: $w=r\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}$. You obtain the equation:
\begin{align}
&\frac {500}r\mathrm e^{-i\theta}=3r +40 i,\quad\text{whence}\quad \frac{25\cdot10^4}{r^2}=9r^2+1600,\\
\implies &\; 9r^4+1600\,r^2-25\cdot 10^4.
\end{align}
This is a quadratic equation in $r^2$, with a reduced discriminant $\Delta'=64\cdot 10^4-9\cdot 25\cdot 10^4 =289\cdot 10^4=17^210^4$.

$r^2$ is the positive root: $-800+1700=900$. The rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

another method hint  : $$w=a+bi \to \frac 1w=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+i\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$$so 
$$\frac{500}{w}=3|w|+40i\\
500(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+i\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2})=3\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+40i\\\to \begin{cases}\frac{500a}{a^2+b^2}=3\sqrt{a^2+b^2} & \\\frac{-500b}{a^2+b^2}=40 & \end{cases}$$